# How to show a list of "shared with me" files in Google Picker

Tags: google-api, google-picker

Google Picker is working fine for the user's own Drive, but I want to add the option to see files shared with the user, as per drive.google.com where you have both My Drive and Shared with me:

[image]

This is the code that gets closest:

```
const sharedDocsView = new window.google.picker.DocsView();
    sharedDocsView.setEnableDrives(true); // adds Shared Drives
    sharedDocsView.setOwnedByMe(false);
    sharedDocsView.setMode(window.google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST);
    pickerBuilder.addView(sharedDocsView);
```

This gets a **Shared Drives** tab, but it starts out empty:

[image]

However, if you start typing in the search field, it then shows any files that match:

[image]

Have experimented with the API, but have not found any combination that will just let the user browse their **Shared with me** files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Remove `.setEnableDrives(true)`, you just need `setOwnedByMe(false)`.

**Explanation:** Judging by your screenshot you don't seem to have any [Shared Drives](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/7212025). These are not the same as shared files, and they have a [different structure](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/enable-shareddrives):

> Shared drives follow different organization, sharing, and ownership models from My Drive.

Shared Drives look like this in your Drive:

[image: Shared Drives view]

When you set the method `.setEnableDrives(true)` you're telling the Picker to include Shared Drives. This makes it prioritize the view of these Drives and the "Shared with me" files are included only in the "background" as searchable items, since these have very different views that are not compatible with each other. For example, this is what your view looks like for me:

[image]

The above view shows the Shared Drive structure but you can still search for your "Shared with me" files. You'll notice that there's also a "Shared with me" tab. I created that view by using only `.setOwnedByMe(false)`. This view doesn't include the Shared Drives, but it shows just the shared files as you want:

[image]

The sample code to create these views is this:

```js
    const shareddrivesview = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
          .setEnableDrives(true)
          .setIncludeFolders(true); // creates just the shared drives view

    const sharedwithmeview = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
          .setOwnedByMe(false); // creates just the shared with me view

    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
        .setDeveloperKey(API_KEY)
        .setAppId(APP_ID)
        .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
        .addView(shareddrivesview)
        .addView(sharedwithmeview)
        .setCallback(pickerCallback)
        .build()

    picker.setVisible(true);
```

Essentially, you don't want to combine `setEnableDrives(true)` with `setOwnedByMe(false)` in the same view unless you want users to have to search their shared files manually. You're better off creating separate views for each of them or remove Shared Drive support if you don't plan to use it.

##### Sources:

- [Shared Drives](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/7212025)
- [Google Picker reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/reference)

Comment: Thanks, the tip of removing the setEnableDrives from my right-hand view and only having setOwnedByMe(false) now made that tab "Shared with me" instead of "Shared Drives" - and the shared files appear without having to search. It's still different to the "Shared with me" the user sees in their own Drive, as no folders shared with them are included in the list, only files. Is that impossible to achieve?

Comment: It seems that it's not possible to have the exact same view. In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/reference) I linked, it says that `setOwnedByMe` and `setIncludeFolders(true)` cannot be combined, so you won't see the shared folders. You should still see the files contained within those folders, though. I think the closest you can get is to use `setIncludeFolders(true)` and also add `.setQuery('-owner:me')`. This is still not exactly the same since it includes the folders and also the files within. The user can also edit the query after the picker loads.

Comment: @Daniel I got the exact same view as in Google Drive by combining  setIncludeFolders(true) & setOwnedByMe

even tough the docs indeed mentions that this is not possible, it solved the issue for me.

Comment: Do you know a way to set the default docs view to list mode? I tried setting new google.picker.DocsView().setMode(google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST); But this removed the grid option completely. Is there a way to set list as default only and keep the grid mode too?